# react-filepond implementing viewing of only supported file types in the file browser

Tags: reactjs, file, file-type, filepond

I've implemented File type validation in React for .fbx files and have done a custom file type detection in fileValidateTypeDetectType.
Additionally, for my application, i want users to see only fbx files in the file browser while selecting files.
Is there a way to add an accept prop, like in HTML file input so the user **can view only fbx files in the file browser**?

Answer (score 0):

Not all browsers support filtering the files shown in the file browse window. It works on MacOS but I have mixed results on Windows.